# How to replace 2 strings (with eachother) simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php, string, function, replace

What I'm trying to do is very simple, but I'm looking to do it most efficiently, preferably using php builtin fns.

```
$str = '1234';
echo replace_function(array('1','3'),array('3','1'),$str);

// output: 3214
```

str_replace,preg_replace would result in 1214, which means it goes through the arrays, replacing matched strings. I'm looking for a solution to simultaneously "switch" these two (or more) strings.

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need string translate:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
<?php
$trans = array("hello" => "hi", "hi" => "hello");
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello", $trans);
// = hello all, I said hi
?>
```

Comment: @Sergi, +1, but be sure to credit where you got the example from, and 2, its always nice to give an example that uses the OP's code.

Comment: Just watch out for false positives.

Comment: I knew there oughtta be something simple like that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$subject = '1234';
$result = preg_replace('/(1)(2)(3)(4)/si', '$3$2$1$4', $subject);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

You can change the pattern to something more generic, such as '/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/'.

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for. I don't know the sequence of the replaced string. Something arbitrary like 3211123 should seamlessly become 1233321.

Comment: That will only work on the specific case of '1235'
you might as well say $result = '3214'


Using '/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/' will change any 4 digits to '3214'

Comment: Pity to get "-2" rather than "Thanks". Glad to know strtr().

Comment: <?php

$subject = "hi all, I said hello";
$result = preg_replace('/(hi)(.+)(hello)/si', '$3$2$1', $subject);
var_dump($result);

?>