# Replacing multiple characters in a string, the fastest way?

Tags: c#, regex, string, performance, replace

I am importing some number of records with multiple `string` fields from an old db to a new db. It seems to be very slow and I suspect it's because I do this:

```
foreach (var oldObj in oldDB)
{
    NewObject newObj = new NewObject();
    newObj.Name = oldObj.Name.Trim().Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š')
        .Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć')
        .Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
    newObj.Surname = oldObj.Surname.Trim().Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š')
        .Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć')
        .Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
    newObj.Address = oldObj.Address.Trim().Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š')
        .Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć')
        .Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
    newObj.Note = oldObj.Note.Trim().Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š')
        .Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć')
        .Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
    /*
    ... some processing ...
    */
}
```

Now, I have read some posts and articles through the Net where I have seen many different thoughts about this. Some say it's better if I'd do regex with `MatchEvaluator`, some say it's the best to leave it as is.

While it's possible that it'd be easier for me to just do a benchmark case for myself, I decided to ask a question here in case someone else has been wondering about the same question, or in case someone knows in advance.

So what is the fastest way to do this in C#?

*EDIT*

I have posted the benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932). At the first sight it looks like Richard's way might be the fastest. However, his way, nor Marc's, would do anything because of the wrong Regex pattern. After correcting the pattern from

```
@"\^@\[\]`\}~\{\\"
```

to

```
@"\^|@|\[|\]|`|\}|~|\{|\\"
```

it appears as if the old way with chained .Replace() calls is the fastest after all

Comment: I would suggest to leave it as is. Maybe try a parrallel foreach ?

Comment: You _suspect_ that's the reason? You should _know_. You need to profile the application in order to fine the bottleneck - don't guess.

Comment: I once asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600177/how-to-replace-two-or-more-strings-with-each-other) and accepted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600320/704144) but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Oded whether I suspect or know is not a question here, the question is how to yield better performance while replacing multiple characters in a string. It is irrelevant, you should assume the `/* ... some processing ... */` part of the sample code is surely not the bottleneck considering I asked the question in this form. Thanks for the constructive comment though.

Comment: My point is that if you don't have the data, you might be doing some micro optimizations, where there is a chance of macro optimizations. Suspecting that a piece of code is the problem doesn't mean it is - you may be focusing your efforts on the _wrong_ problem, that's all.

Comment: @Oded - and the real issue was your tone in your first comment. For whatever reason I've been seeing this a lot lately on this forum and it's going to stop people from using it. Be careful with your tone and how you're perceived - arrogance is not a desirable trait. Nevertheless, I fully agree with you because when trying to find performance bottlenecks a hunch can **sometimes** lead you down the wrong path and yield no gain.

Comment: I am sorry you have read a certain tone into my first comment - I try to keep my tone neutral and factual. I also like to keep my comments short.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs guys.
I wrote a quick and dirty benchmark to test your inputs. I have tested parsing 4 strings with 500.000 iterations and have done 4 passes. The result is as follows:

```
*** Pass 1
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 814 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 916 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 943 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 2551 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 215 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 1008 ms

*** Pass 2
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 786 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 920 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 905 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 2515 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 217 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 1025 ms

*** Pass 3
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 775 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 903 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 931 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 2529 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 214 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 1022 ms

*** Pass 4
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 799 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 908 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 938 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 2592 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 225 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 1050 ms
```

The code for this benchmark is below. Please review the code and confirm that @Richard has got the fastest way. Note that I haven't checked if outputs were correct, I assumed they were.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StringReplaceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static string test1 = "A^@[BCD";
        static string test2 = "E]FGH\\";
        static string test3 = "ijk`l}m";
        static string test4 = "nopq~{r";

        static readonly Dictionary<char, string> repl =
            new Dictionary<char, string> 
            { 
                {'^', "Č"}, {'@', "Ž"}, {'[', "Š"}, {']', "Ć"}, {'`', "ž"}, {'}', "ć"}, {'~', "č"}, {'{', "š"}, {'\\', "Đ"} 
            };

        static readonly Regex replaceRegex;

        static Program() // static initializer 
        {
            StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder().Append('[');
            foreach (var key in repl.Keys)
                pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(key.ToString()));
            pattern.Append(']');
            replaceRegex = new Regex(pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        public static string Sanitize(string input)
        {
            return replaceRegex.Replace(input, match =>
            {
                return repl[match.Value[0]];
            });
        } 

        static string DoGeneralReplace(string input) 
        { 
            var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
            return sb.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ').ToString(); 
        }

        //Method for replacing chars with a mapping 
        static string Replace(string input, IDictionary<char, char> replacementMap)
        {
            return replacementMap.Keys
                .Aggregate(input, (current, oldChar)
                    => current.Replace(oldChar, replacementMap[oldChar]));
        } 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                DoIt(i);
        }

        static void DoIt(int n)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            int idx = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("*** Pass " + n.ToString());
            // old way
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = test1.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result2 = test2.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result3 = test3.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result4 = test4.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>();
            replacements.Add('^', 'Č');
            replacements.Add('@', 'Ž');
            replacements.Add('[', 'Š');
            replacements.Add(']', 'Ć');
            replacements.Add('`', 'ž');
            replacements.Add('}', 'ć');
            replacements.Add('~', 'č');
            replacements.Add('{', 'š');
            replacements.Add('\\', 'Đ');

            // logicnp way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                char[] charArray1 = test1.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray1.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test1[i], out newChar))
                        charArray1[i] = newChar;
                }
                string result1 = new string(charArray1);

                char[] charArray2 = test2.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray2.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test2[i], out newChar))
                        charArray2[i] = newChar;
                }
                string result2 = new string(charArray2);

                char[] charArray3 = test3.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray3.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test3[i], out newChar))
                        charArray3[i] = newChar;
                }
                string result3 = new string(charArray3);

                char[] charArray4 = test4.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray4.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test4[i], out newChar))
                        charArray4[i] = newChar;
                }
                string result4 = new string(charArray4);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // oleksii way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = DoGeneralReplace(test1);
                string result2 = DoGeneralReplace(test2);
                string result3 = DoGeneralReplace(test3);
                string result4 = DoGeneralReplace(test4);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // André Christoffer Andersen way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = Replace(test1, replacements);
                string result2 = Replace(test2, replacements);
                string result3 = Replace(test3, replacements);
                string result4 = Replace(test4, replacements);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // Richard way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\^|@|\[|\]|`|\}|~|\{|\\");
            MatchEvaluator eval = match =>
            {
                switch (match.Value)
                {
                    case "^": return "Č";
                    case "@": return "Ž";
                    case "[": return "Š";
                    case "]": return "Ć";
                    case "`": return "ž";
                    case "}": return "ć";
                    case "~": return "č";
                    case "{": return "š";
                    case "\\": return "Đ";
                    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected match!");
                }
            };
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = reg.Replace(test1, eval);
                string result2 = reg.Replace(test2, eval);
                string result3 = reg.Replace(test3, eval);
                string result4 = reg.Replace(test4, eval);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // Marc Gravell way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = Sanitize(test1);
                string result2 = Sanitize(test2);
                string result3 = Sanitize(test3);
                string result4 = Sanitize(test4);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT June 2020**
Since this Q&A is still getting hits, I wanted to update it with additional input from user1664043 using StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny, this time compiled using .NET Core 3.1, and here are the results:

```
*** Pass 1
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 199 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 296 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 416 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 870 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 1722 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 395 ms
user1664043 (StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny) way completed in 459 ms

*** Pass 2
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 215 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 239 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 341 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 758 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 1591 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 354 ms
user1664043 (StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny) way completed in 426 ms

*** Pass 3
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 199 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 265 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 337 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 817 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 1666 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 373 ms
user1664043 (StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny) way completed in 412 ms

*** Pass 4
Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in 199 ms
logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in 230 ms
oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in 324 ms
André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in 791 ms
Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in 1699 ms
Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in 359 ms
user1664043 (StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny) way completed in 413 ms
```

And the updated code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test.StringReplace
{
    class Program
    {
        static string test1 = "A^@[BCD";
        static string test2 = "E]FGH\\";
        static string test3 = "ijk`l}m";
        static string test4 = "nopq~{r";

        static readonly Dictionary<char, string> repl =
            new Dictionary<char, string>
            {
                {'^', "Č"}, {'@', "Ž"}, {'[', "Š"}, {']', "Ć"}, {'`', "ž"}, {'}', "ć"}, {'~', "č"}, {'{', "š"}, {'\\', "Đ"}
            };

        static readonly Regex replaceRegex;

        static readonly char[] badChars = new char[] { '^', '@', '[', ']', '`', '}', '~', '{', '\\' };

        static readonly char[] replacementChars = new char[] { 'Č', 'Ž', 'Š', 'Ć', 'ž', 'ć', 'č', 'š', 'Đ' };

        static Program() // static initializer 
        {
            StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder().Append('[');
            foreach (var key in repl.Keys)
                pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(key.ToString()));
            pattern.Append(']');
            replaceRegex = new Regex(pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        public static string Sanitize(string input)
        {
            return replaceRegex.Replace(input, match =>
            {
                return repl[match.Value[0]];
            });
        }

        static string DoGeneralReplace(string input)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
            return sb.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ').ToString();
        }

        //Method for replacing chars with a mapping 
        static string Replace(string input, IDictionary<char, char> replacementMap)
        {
            return replacementMap.Keys
                .Aggregate(input, (current, oldChar)
                    => current.Replace(oldChar, replacementMap[oldChar]));
        }

        static string ReplaceCharsWithIndexOfAny(string sIn)
        {
            int replChar = sIn.IndexOfAny(badChars);
            if (replChar < 0)
                return sIn;

            // Don't even bother making a copy unless you know you have something to swap
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sIn, 0, replChar, sIn.Length + 10);
            while (replChar >= 0 && replChar < sIn.Length)
            {
                var c = replacementChars[replChar];
                sb.Append(c);

                ////// This approach lets you swap a char for a string or to remove some
                ////// If you had a straight char for char swap, you could just have your repl chars in an array with the same ordinals and do it all in 2 lines matching the ordinals.
                ////c = c switch
                ////{
                ////    ////case "^":
                ////    ////    c = "Č";
                ////    ////    ...
                ////    '\ufeff' => null,
                ////    _ => replacementChars[replChar],
                ////};

                ////if (c != null)
                ////{
                ////    sb.Append(c);
                ////}

                replChar++; // skip over what we just replaced
                if (replChar < sIn.Length)
                {
                    int nextRepChar = sIn.IndexOfAny(badChars, replChar);
                    sb.Append(sIn, replChar, (nextRepChar > 0 ? nextRepChar : sIn.Length) - replChar);
                    replChar = nextRepChar;
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                DoIt(i);
        }

        static void DoIt(int n)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            int idx = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("*** Pass " + n.ToString());
            // old way
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = test1.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result2 = test2.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result3 = test3.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
                string result4 = test4.Replace('^', 'Č').Replace('@', 'Ž').Replace('[', 'Š').Replace(']', 'Ć').Replace('`', 'ž').Replace('}', 'ć').Replace('~', 'č').Replace('{', 'š').Replace('\\', 'Đ');
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Old (Chained String.Replace()) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>();
            replacements.Add('^', 'Č');
            replacements.Add('@', 'Ž');
            replacements.Add('[', 'Š');
            replacements.Add(']', 'Ć');
            replacements.Add('`', 'ž');
            replacements.Add('}', 'ć');
            replacements.Add('~', 'č');
            replacements.Add('{', 'š');
            replacements.Add('\\', 'Đ');

            // logicnp way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                char[] charArray1 = test1.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray1.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test1[i], out newChar))
                        charArray1[i] = newChar;
                }

                string result1 = new string(charArray1);

                char[] charArray2 = test2.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray2.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test2[i], out newChar))
                        charArray2[i] = newChar;
                }

                string result2 = new string(charArray2);

                char[] charArray3 = test3.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray3.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test3[i], out newChar))
                        charArray3[i] = newChar;
                }

                string result3 = new string(charArray3);

                char[] charArray4 = test4.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray4.Length; i++)
                {
                    char newChar;
                    if (replacements.TryGetValue(test4[i], out newChar))
                        charArray4[i] = newChar;
                }

                string result4 = new string(charArray4);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("logicnp (ToCharArray) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // oleksii way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = DoGeneralReplace(test1);
                string result2 = DoGeneralReplace(test2);
                string result3 = DoGeneralReplace(test3);
                string result4 = DoGeneralReplace(test4);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("oleksii (StringBuilder) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // André Christoffer Andersen way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = Replace(test1, replacements);
                string result2 = Replace(test2, replacements);
                string result3 = Replace(test3, replacements);
                string result4 = Replace(test4, replacements);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("André Christoffer Andersen (Lambda w/ Aggregate) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // Richard way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\^|@|\[|\]|`|\}|~|\{|\\");
            MatchEvaluator eval = match =>
            {
                switch (match.Value)
                {
                    case "^": return "Č";
                    case "@": return "Ž";
                    case "[": return "Š";
                    case "]": return "Ć";
                    case "`": return "ž";
                    case "}": return "ć";
                    case "~": return "č";
                    case "{": return "š";
                    case "\\": return "Đ";
                    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected match!");
                }
            };
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = reg.Replace(test1, eval);
                string result2 = reg.Replace(test2, eval);
                string result3 = reg.Replace(test3, eval);
                string result4 = reg.Replace(test4, eval);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Richard (Regex w/ MatchEvaluator) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // Marc Gravell way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = Sanitize(test1);
                string result2 = Sanitize(test2);
                string result3 = Sanitize(test3);
                string result4 = Sanitize(test4);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Marc Gravell (Static Regex) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

            // user1664043 way
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (idx = 0; idx < 500000; idx++)
            {
                string result1 = ReplaceCharsWithIndexOfAny(test1);
                string result2 = ReplaceCharsWithIndexOfAny(test2);
                string result3 = ReplaceCharsWithIndexOfAny(test3);
                string result4 = ReplaceCharsWithIndexOfAny(test4);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("user1664043 (StringBuilder w/ IndexOfAny) way completed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that surprising that `Regex` is faster. It's built to search strings with ridiculous efficiency. Always remember, Law of the instrument is bad - leverage the technologies that are built for what you're trying to do so don't be afraid to use Regex. C# isn't good at everything just because there's an API for it. Good question and good benchmarks @Dejan.

Comment: I'd also add one thing too - your test strings are very short. While this may be the case for your real data (in which case your benchmarking is just fine and spot on), it skews the results for longer strings, with different amounts of characters to replace etc. I suspect this is responsible for the relatively good performance of string.Replace - it does create the string over and over again (though only if something changes), but both the loop and the string result is very small, so it doesn't cost much. The difference would be much more pronounced on long strings.

Comment: I've tested with larger strings with more replacements, and the results are quite predictable, but they do change some things. First, on larger strings, StringBuilder starts getting faster than String (the cost of creating the SB itself starts being offset by the savings in repeated creation of new strings). In the opposite way, Richard's solution is getting better and better, because it only depends on the length of the string linearly, not to mention that it adds much less memory pressure compared to string.Replace.

Comment: I think the Regex method is the fastest because the pattern is missing '[' at the beginning of the string and a ']' at the end of the string. 

With the sample shown, no replacement is done because we have no match! 

I think the huge difference in time between the two regex methods, can simply explained by that.

Comment: @SergeWeinstock you are right. See the original question, there is an EDIT at the end of it.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević can you update the code in this answer to reflect this fact otherwise it shows incorrect results

Comment: I ran this test in 3 versions (diff length and replacements) and logicnp was always best, followed by oleksii. He was best even in original test for me? .NET 4.5, Release, Win7, i7

Comment: pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(key.ToString())) - it doesn't escape ']' and '}' chars. So, generated pattern is incorrect.

Comment: Just to be thorough, there isn't an .IndexOfAny() attempt in here.  You can do a variation on the StringBuilder approach that does a single pass using IndexOfAny on the original instead of chained .Replace()s.  For instances where none of the chars are in the input, you wouldn't even have to create the StringBuilder, which would make that *many* times faster

Comment: To summarize: the original numbers apparently do not reflect the fact that the regexes were broken.  I re-ran the test (adding my proposed method) adding validation that the results were correct.   Then I took out the validation and re-ran them.  I also ran the MatchEvaluator method using the same static regex, a regex created in the test run, and using Regex.Replace(input,pattern,eval).  The MatchEvaluator method was always the slowest.  Given the test data, chained StringBuilder.Replace was always the fastest, then ToCharArray, string.Replace chain, my method, Marc's, then Richard's

Comment: Caveat: all the test inputs are short and contain 2-3 characters to replace.  Larger inputs with more uncertainty on whether there is anything to replace radically change the performance characteristics of the various methods.

Answer (score 15):

> the fastest way

The only way is to compare the performance yourself. Try as in the Q, using `StringBuilder` and also `Regex.Replace`.

But micro-benchmarks don't consider the scope of the whole system. If this method is only a small fraction of the overall system its performance probably doesn't matter to the overall application's performance.

Some notes:

1. Using `String` as above (I assume) will create lots of intermediate strings: more work for the GC. But it is simple.
2. Using `StringBuilder` allows the same underlying data to be modified with each replace. This creates less garbage. It is almost as simple as using `String`.
3. Using a [`regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) is most complex (because you need to have code to work out the replacement), but allows a single expression. I would expect this to be slower unless the list of replacements is very large and replacements are rare in the input string (ie. most replace method calls replace nothing, just costing a search through the string).

I expect #2 would be slightly quicker over repeated use (thousands of times) due to less GC load.

For the regex approach you need something like:

```
newObj.Name = Regex.Replace(oldObj.Name.Trim(), @"[@^\[\]`}~{\\]", match => {
  switch (match.Value) {
    case "^": return "Č";
    case "@": return "Ž";
    case "[": return "Š";
    case "]": return "Ć";
    case "`": return "ž";
    case "}": return "ć";
    case "~": return "č";
    case "{": return "š";
    case "\\": return "Đ";
    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected match!");
  }
});
```

This could be done in a reusable way by parameterising with a [`Dictionary<char,char>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to hold the replacements and reusable [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please take a look at the [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932) I posted as another answer.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević oops on the regex typo... I knew I needed a character class (correcting).

Comment: However when I fixed the typo the result was poor... even slower than Marc's static regex.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Worth noting the regex engine caches the last few (15 IIRC) regexes passed to the static methods, so in this test I wouldn't expect to see any difference in explicitly creating a Regex instance (only the first use of the static method will be slower for the compile).

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>();
// populate replacements

string str = "mystring";
char []charArray = str.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    char newChar;
    if (replacements.TryGetValue(str[i], out newChar))
    charArray[i] = newChar;
}

string newStr = new string(charArray);
```

Comment: +1 I will only try to add an IndexOfAny to avoid loops on string when not needed

Comment: @Steve - IndexOfAny will internally use a loop too. There is no way to avoid a single loop for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please take a look at the [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932) I posted as another answer.

Comment: @logicnp True, but IndexOfAny is incredibly fast - if it's relatively common that the string doesn't have anything to replace, it could mean significant savings (including completely removing the creation of a new char[] - not a large cost, but still significant in the scope of things). Note that both `ToCharArray` and the later `new string(charArray)` copy the char data of the string *and* allocate the memory required.

Comment: Most of the time is spent on the Dictionary lookup. That can be avoided by using a char array with the key char as the index and the replacement char as the value. Then you check for '\0' to see if there is a replacement char or not.

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is to use a `StringBuilder` class for this.

You can first refactor the code to a single method

```
public string DoGeneralReplace(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    sb.Replace("^", "Č")
      .Replace("@", "Ž") ...;
}


//usage
foreach (var oldObj in oldDB)
{
    NewObject newObj = new NewObject();
    newObj.Name = DoGeneralReplace(oldObj.Name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please take a look at the [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932) I posted as another answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use lambda expressions for this using Aggregate on a char map:

```
  //Method for replacing chars with a mapping
  static string Replace(string input, IDictionary<char, char> replacementMap) {
      return replacementMap.Keys
          .Aggregate(input, (current, oldChar) 
              => current.Replace(oldChar, replacementMap[oldChar]));
  }
```

You can run this as follows:

```
  private static void Main(string[] args) {
      //Char to char map using <oldChar, newChar>
      var charMap = new Dictionary<char, char>();
      charMap.Add('-', 'D'); charMap.Add('|', 'P'); charMap.Add('@', 'A');

      //Your input string
      string myString = "asgjk--@dfsg||jshd--f@jgsld-kj|rhgunfh-@-nsdflngs";

      //Your own replacement method
      myString = Replace(myString, charMap);

      //out: myString = "asgjkDDAdfsgPPjshdDDfAjgsldDkjPrhgunfhDADnsdflngs"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please take a look at the [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932) I posted as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would *try* doing something like:

```
    static readonly Dictionary<char, string> replacements =
       new Dictionary<char, string>
    {
        {']',"Ć"}, {'~', "č"} // etc
    };
    static readonly Regex replaceRegex;
    static YourUtilityType() // static initializer
    {
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder().Append('[');
        foreach(var key in replacements.Keys)
            pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(key.ToString()));
        pattern.Append(']');
        replaceRegex = new Regex(pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
    public static string Sanitize(string input)
    {
        return replaceRegex.Replace(input, match =>
        {
            return replacements[match.Value[0]];
        });
    }
```

This has a single place to maintain (at the top), and builds a pre-compiled `Regex` to handle the replacements. All the overhead is done only one (hence `static`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please take a look at the [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way/11900932#11900932) I posted as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid StringBuilder approach using IndexOfAny:

```
protected String ReplaceChars(String sIn)
{
    int replChar = sIn.IndexOfAny(badChars);
    if (replChar < 0)
        return sIn;

    // Don't even bother making a copy unless you know you have something to swap
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sIn, 0, replChar, sIn.Length + 10);
    while (replChar >= 0 && replChar < sIn.Length)
    {
        char? c = sIn[replChar];
        string s = null;
        // This approach lets you swap a char for a string or to remove some
        // If you had a straight char for char swap, you could just have your repl chars in an array with the same ordinals and do it all in 2 lines matching the ordinals.
        switch (c)
        {
            case "^": c = "Č";
            ...
            case '\ufeff': c = null; break;
        }
        if (s != null) sb.Append(s);
        else if (c != null) sb.Append(c);

        replChar++; // skip over what we just replaced
        if (replChar < sIn.Length)
        {
            int nextRepChar = sIn.IndexOfAny(badChars, replChar);
            sb.Append(sIn, replChar, (nextRepChar > 0 ? nextRepChar : sIn.Length) - replChar);
            replChar = nextRepChar;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was curious about this and added your input to the benchmark. Please see the edited accepted answer for the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET Core 2.1, using `string.Create` with `switch` statement might be the fastest way.

```
public static string ReplaceChars(s) {
    return string.Create(s.Length, s, (cc, s) =>
    {
        s.AsSpan().CopyTo(cc); // or just s.CopyTo(cc) in .NET 6+ 
        for (int i = 0; i < cc.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (cc[i])
            {
                case '^': cc[i] = 'Č'; break;
                case '@': cc[i] = 'Ž'; break;
                case '[': cc[i] = 'Š'; break;
                case ']': cc[i] = 'Ć'; break;
                case '`': cc[i] = 'ž'; break;
                case '}': cc[i] = 'ć'; break;
                case '~': cc[i] = 'č'; break;
                case '{': cc[i] = 'š'; break;
                case '\\': cc[i] = 'Đ'; break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

From my benchmark, the speed is fastest comparing to using temporary `char[]`, `RegEx` and `StringBuilder.Replace`, by a factor of 4 to 10. The main advantage of the above method is

1. By using `string.Create`, no temporary buffer needed.
2. `Span.CopyTo` will be optimized by the framework
3. Loop through the buffer only once and directly access to the `Span`.
4. No extra GC allocation.

Comment: @Mr.Squirrel.Downy how so?

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I mistakenly thought he wanted to create a safe "path string". If it's a fixed replace pair, you're right.