# Replace multiple words to other words in a string from a list of words

Tags: c#, regex

This question is similar to: 
[Replace multiple words in a string from a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226691/replace-multiple-words-in-a-string-from-a-list-of-words)

The accepted solution there is the following

```
string cleaned = Regex.Replace(input, "\\b" + string.Join("\\b|\\b",BAD_WORDS) + "\\b", "")
```

However, in my case I want to replace each "word" from the list with its bold version (basically add  in the beginning and  at the end)

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, $@"\b(?:{string.Join("|",BAD_WORDS)})\b", "<b>$&</b>")`

Comment: You're taking code written by others, and are asking others to modify it to suit your needs, and there is no indication of any effort of your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(input, $@"\b(?:{string.Join("|",BAD_WORDS)})\b", "<b>$&</b>")
```

This is the solution suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew - works perfectly