# manipulating strings

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove some special characters from a string.
I have got the following string

```
[_fesd][009] Statement
```

and I want to get rid of all '_' '['  and ']'
I managed to remove the first characters with TrimStart and I get   fesd][009] Statement

How should I remove the special characters from the middle of my string?

Currently Im using the following code

```
string newStr = str.Trim(new Char[] { '[', ']', '_' });
```

where str is the strin that should be manupulated and the result should be stored in newStr

Comment: I would read up on Regex mate. (Regular Expressions). CLeanest way to do things like this.

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem..

Comment: If performance is a consideration, you may want to review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899668/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-the-fastest-way

Answer (score 6):

```
string newStr = str.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("_", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newStr = Regex.Replace("[_fesd][009] Statement", "(\\[)|(\\])|(_)", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Replace with string.Empty as the string to replace with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Linq` for it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = @"[_fesd][009] Statement";
    var unwanted = @"_[]";

    var sanitizedS = s
        .Where(i => !unwanted.Contains(i))
        .Aggregate<char, string>("", (a, b) => a + b);

    Console.WriteLine(sanitizedS);
    // output: fesd009 Statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chars = new Char[] { '[', ']', '_' };
var newValue = new String(str.Where(x => !chars.Contains(x)).ToArray());
```