# Regular expression in C# (regex from PHP)

Tags: c#, php, regex

I have small problem. I try to write a function to extract something in C# (I have to convert a regular expression from PHP to C#).

I generally write it like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public String PregReplace(this String input, string[] pattern, string[] replacements)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern[i], replacements[i]);
    }

    return input;
  }
}
```

But I have a problem with these examples (code in PHP)

```
preg_replace('@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu', ' ', $result);
preg_replace('@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu', "\n\$0", $result);
```

But when I use this regulax expression in C#

```
String[] pattern = new String[2]{"@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu", "@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu"};
String[] replace = new String[2]{" ", "\n\$0"};
input.PregReplace(pattern , replace );  //my new function
```

I don't have any differences in input (I don't catch a regular expression).
Can you help me with my function? Do I have error in regex?

EDIT:
I changed code to:

```
String[] pattern = new String[2]{"<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>", "</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))"};
String[] replace = new String[2]{" ", "\n\\$0"};

input = "input = "><head><title>something</title></head><body>sdegsehgaeg<frame>aggsd</frame></";
string s = input.PregReplace(pattern, replace);
```

In answer I get

```
> <body>sdegsehgaeg
\<frame>aggsd
\</frame></
```

It is

```
> <body>sdegsehgaeg\n\\<frame>aggsd\n\\</frame></
```

This is only to much char \ for \n\$0. If I change \n\$0 to \n\$0 I get error (urecognized escape sequence)

Ok I solved problem (\n$0)

Thank you for help.

Comment: I asked for a repolace function before, it doesn't answer your Regex related question but [this nice answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600320/704144) can provide you an alternative.

Comment: There should be a replace now. Are you using it like this? string s = input.PregReplace(pattern, replace); Remember, the function is returning a NEW string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` in your code, and the `siu` and `iu` after your last `@`. In php you need those modifiers, in C# you would call some `RegexOptions` if necessary.

Comment: You can use [this site](http://regexhero.net/tester/) to check syntax as well. I think there are others around but I find this one good for C#.